# How can I check the caller url from my application in angular?

Tags: angular

Our application will be accesible via a button on another application (from a different domain). We need to make sure our application is only accesible from that endpoint. How can we manage that?

I have tried using NavigationEnd but it's not showing the origin url, it only shows \

Extra info: Our front is in angular 11 and we are not allowed to use params on the url to check the origin of the call.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `document.referrer` in [Guard](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)?

```
@Injectable()
class CanView implements CanActivate {

  canActivate(): boolean {
    return document.referrer.includes('https://stackoverflow.com');
  }
}
```

I would also suggest you save this to a service, so user can refresh.